# Is my proof that $\forall x: x\notin x$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Is my proof that $\forall x: x\notin x$ correct?

*Proof.* Let us notice that for all $x$ it's true that $$\neg \big[x\in x\iff \neg (x\in x)\big]\tag{1}$$ but $(1)$ is logically equivalente to $$x\in x\oplus \neg (x\in x)\tag{2}$$ where $\oplus$ is the [*exclusive or*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or). So, at most, one of the cases in $(2)$ is true. If $x\in x$ for all $x$ then in particular $\emptyset\in \emptyset$ so it must be that for all $x, x\notin x$.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity

Answer (score 10):

If you make the quantifiers explicit, you get
$$\forall x(\neg \big[x\in x\iff \neg (x\in x)\big]\tag{1})$$
which is logically equivalent to
$$\forall x(x\in x\oplus \neg (x\in x))$$
But you are interpreting it as
$$(\forall x(x\in x))\oplus (\forall x(\neg (x\in x)))$$
which is not the same thing at all! So you haven't proved anything, I'm afraid.

---

Here is a similar 'proof' that all integers are zero:

For all $x\in\Bbb Z$, it is true that
$$\neg (x=0 \iff x\ne 0)$$
which is logically equivalent to
$$x=0\oplus x\ne 0$$
In particular, $0=0$. So it must be that for all $x$, $x=0$.

Comment: (+1) for the nice analogue fake-proof.